# Getting File Version Information fails -- But not for me

Tags: c++, winapi, version

I am trying to get version information from a file. My code works perfectly for me, but fails on several others' machines. Because I can't reproduce the bug, I'm having quite a time finding the issue.

Does anyone see anything majorly wrong with this?

```
LPBYTE versionInformationBlock;
struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
    WORD wLanguage;
    WORD wCodePage;
} *langBlockPointer;
UINT translationsCount;

void fileData::enumVersionInformationBlock()
{
    bits.set(VERSIONINFOCHECKED);
    disable64.disableFS(); //Shut down WOW64
    DWORD zero = 0;
    DWORD lengthOfVersionData =
    GetFileVersionInfoSize(getFileName().c_str(),&zero);
    if (!lengthOfVersionData)
    {
        disable64.enableFS();
        return;
    }
    versionInformationBlock = new BYTE[lengthOfVersionData];
    GetFileVersionInfo(getFileName().c_str(),zero,lengthOfVersionData,versionInformationBlock);
    VerQueryValue(versionInformationBlock,L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation",(LPVOID*)&langBlockPointer,&translationsCount);
    translationsCount /= sizeof(struct LANGANDCODEPAGE);
    disable64.enableFS();
}
std::wstring fileData::getVersionInformationString(const std::wstring& str)
{
    if (!bits[VERSIONINFOCHECKED])
        enumVersionInformationBlock();
    if (!versionInformationBlock)
        return L"!VERINFO: NOT PE FILE!";
    LPCTSTR retString;
    UINT retStringLength;
    std::wstring result;
    static const wchar_t hexChars[] = L"0123456789ABCDEF";
    wchar_t hexLanguage[26] = L"\\StringFileInfo\\        \\";
    for( size_t idx = 0; idx < translationsCount; idx++ )
    {
        hexLanguage[16] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wLanguage >> 12) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[17] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wLanguage >> 8 ) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[18] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wLanguage >> 4 ) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[19] = *(hexChars + ( langBlockPointer[idx].wLanguage        & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[20] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wCodePage >> 12) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[21] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wCodePage >> 8 ) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[22] = *(hexChars + ((langBlockPointer[idx].wCodePage >> 4 ) & 0x0F));
        hexLanguage[23] = *(hexChars + ( langBlockPointer[idx].wCodePage        & 0x0F));
        std::wstring targetResource(hexLanguage,25);
        targetResource.append(str);
        if (!VerQueryValue(versionInformationBlock,targetResource.c_str(),(LPVOID *)&retString,&retStringLength))
        {
            return std::wstring(L"!DOESN'T APPER TO EXIST IN FILE! ERROR: ").append(boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(GetLastError()));
        }
        retStringLength--;
        if (!result.empty())
            result.append(L" / ");
        std::wstring toAppend;
        toAppend.assign(retString,retStringLength);
        boost::algorithm::trim(toAppend);
        result.append(toAppend);
    }
    return result;
}
std::wstring fileData::getVerCompany()
{
    return getVersionInformationString(L"CompanyName");
}
~fileData()
{
    if (versionInformationBlock)
        delete [] versionInformationBlock;
};
```

What's really bugging me is that it isn't throwing any of my error messages... it keeps returning garbage.

Any ideas?

Billy3

Comment: I'm sorry all... turns out all the complaining users were using an old copy of the program which had not yet had this function implemented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm. Seems Stackoverflow beats the heck out of me if it isn't answered.....

Billy3

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

- Retrieve the reason for `GetFileVersion`'s failure by using `GetLastError`
- Tell us what OS it works on and what OS it doesn't
- Check if `GetFileVersionInfo` succeeds or not (again `GetLastError`)
- Read the **Remarks** section of the MSDN documentation of the abovementioned functions repeatedly and check if you are not missing something.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not checking for errors from many of the system calls you are using.  For example, `GetFileVersionInfo` will return zero if there is an error getting the data, at which point you can call `GetLastError` to find out what the specific failure was.  Likewise, `GetFileVersionInfoSize` will return zero if there is an error.  It looks like you check for that failure but don't bother to log the system error code (again, use `GetLastError` to retrieve that value).

I suggest you add the error handling code for the system calls you are using.  Most likely one of those is failing, and probably leaving a very meaningful error code for you to inspect with `GetLastError`.